# Deserialization of different objects Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, gson, json-deserialization

I have a problem with deserialization list of different objects. Help me please to resolve this issue. This JSON is required by the customer side.

```
{"result":[  
      {  
         "id": 5,
         "op":[  
            0,
            { "description": "hello world" }
         ]}]
}
```

I have:

```
public class Transaction {
    public int id;
    public List<Object> op;
}

public class ResponseTransactions {
    public List<Transaction> result;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
List< List<Transaction>> list= gson.fromJson(json,  
ResponseTransactions.class))
```

After that I must call LinkedTreeMap:

```
String description = (LinkedTreeMap)Transaction.op.get(1).get("description");
```

But I want to use like this:

```
public class Operation{
     public String description;
}

public class Transaction {
    public String id;
    public List<Operation> op;
}
```

Comment: Why is there a zero as the first element in `[  
            0,
            { "description": "hello world" }
         ]` ?

Comment: Because of it's an architecture from bitshares team. It's a blockchain.

Comment: What is the general format of the list? Can it be anything? What do you want to do with the elements that do not have a description?

Comment: It's a static format for JSON. I want to remove them and keep only objects with description.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would have a dissimilar collection of objects  cast into a list of concrete objects , but if thats what is required, you might want to look at a custom Deserializer. Here's a very informative link on how to create a custom deserializer for gson lib.
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics
In your deserializer, you'll need to skip any JsonElement which is not of type "Operation"